# is utmcsr cookie unnecessary when utmgclid is set?

Tags: php, cookies, google-analytics

I'm using PHP-GA lib, which provides a PHP implemention of GA: http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/

When a user comes to my website from an Adwords link, utmcsr (source) cookie is NOT set, and utmgclid (Google click ID) is set instead.

PHP-GA does not allow me to send Campaign tracking data to GA if the utmcsr cookie is not set. So I wonder if it is ok when I just send the utmgclid and NO utmcsr? (yes, I need to modify PHP-GA lib for that). Is all Campaign tracking data (especially Source/Medium) still correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very very late answer, but I guess better late than never. I noticed that it is better to set source "google" and medium "cpc" if utmgclid parameter exists. Otherwise the data is not consistent for ecommerce tracking (for example, comparing Assisted Conversions and Sales Performance).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I almost forgot this question of mine. It's exactly what I did: manually set **utmcsr** by modifying PHP-GA code. And it works well till now :). I still want to mark your answer as accepted, for the spirit of Stackoverflow! ^^ Thanks again!

Comment: @donkapone, when utmgclid has a value different to "direct" always means that the adquisition is by adwords?

Comment: Yes. As far as I know, utmcglid cookie is only set by google adwords.